# How to send URL parameter from react router to a toolbar?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In a example below in ReactJS, where a toolbar will be in app.js and using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

```
render(){
return (
<div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <Route
                        render={({ location }) => (
                            <div>
                                <Toolbar />
                                <TransitionGroup>
                                    <CSSTransition key={location.pathname} classNames="fade" timeout={200}>
                                        <Switch location={location} >
                                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                                            <Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} />
                                        </Switch>
                                    </CSSTransition>
                                </TransitionGroup>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    />
                </Router>
            </div>
);
```

How can I read :id in Toolbar component? I am planning to have a fixed toolbar and route changes below toolbar. Can someone help?

I need this information to add route specific navigation to toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper method is that you have to give `ToolBar` inside `UserDetails`.
Or Use `react-redux` it will give the best solution.
For this case you can pass a `function` to change the `state` of this `class` .Change `Route` to :

```
<Route exact path="/user/:id" render={(props) => <UserDetails changeParentState={this.changeParentState} />}/>
```

inside `UserDetails` class call the function with id :

```
this.props.changeParentState(this.props.match.params.id);
```

`changeParentState` function :

```
const changeParentState = (id) => this.setState({id});
```

change the `<Toolbar />` to:

```
<Toolbar id={this.state.id}/>
```

Comment: Such a long way in react ... Thanks for the answer

Comment: This is not a good way to do this, in my opinion. This doesn't require redux.

Comment: Any alternative instead of using react-redux? Meaning a simple global store for reactjs

Comment: Hi @Colin , your answer is good !!
Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Toolbar = ({ location }) => {
  const url = location.pathname;
  const slashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
  const idParam = url.substr(slashIndex + 1)
  return <p>params --> {idParam}</p>
};

const User = () => {
  return <h1>user</h1>
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Toolbar} />
        <Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/044lp0x06l).

(Try changing the URL and you'll see the param changing.)

Comment: Hi Colin, Unfortunately, this is not what I was trying to achieve, I want to have a common <Toolbar /> with different <Route path="*" /> and get the route parameters in <Toolbar /> component.

Comment: Ah, I see – I've updated example with something that should work, but it's a bit hacky.